# C# in Visual studio 2012. How do I make it debug in 64 bit mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

Hi I have a simple C# solution.
It contains a single Exe project and 2 Dll projects.

All of the code is compiled to "AnyCPU". But when I debug it, it runs as 32 bit.
How do I fix this?

I can change the solution to compile to x64, But I think it misses the point.

(Windows 7, 64 bit. Visual Studio 2012 ultimate)

Thanks

Comment: Your code wasn't compiled to AnyCPU.  Confusing the solution's platform name for the target platform is a very common mistake.  Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Compile tab.  *Those* settings determine the bitness.  Untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox, select AnyCPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click your project in solution explorer.

Click properties.

Go to the build tab.

Ensure you have `All configurations` and the `Any CPU` platform *name* selected at the top of the properties page.

Ensure the platform target matches the selected platform *name* above, `AnyCPU` (yes, these can get out of sync). Deselect `Prefer 32-bit`.

Go.